# OutofMemory exception while building docker images asp.net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, gitlab

While building asp.net core based docker image I am periodically facing the following exception

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.300/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error :  [/src/OrchestratorReverseProxy/OrchestratorReverseProxy.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.300/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error : Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException. [/src/OrchestratorReverseProxy/OrchestratorReverseProxy.csproj]
```

Docker File

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 12201
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["OrchestratorReverseProxy/OrchestratorReverseProxy.csproj", "OrchestratorReverseProxy/"]
RUN dotnet restore "OrchestratorReverseProxy/OrchestratorReverseProxy.csproj" /p:EnableDefaultItems=false
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/OrchestratorReverseProxy"
RUN dotnet build "OrchestratorReverseProxy.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "OrchestratorReverseProxy.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OrchestratorReverseProxy.dll"]
```

Build Logs

```
 Restore completed in 395.8 ms for /src/OrchestratorReverseProxy/OrchestratorReverseProxy.csproj.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.700/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error :  [/src/OrchestratorReverseProxy/OrchestratorReverseProxy.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.700/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error : Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.ExtraAnnotations' threw an exception. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Comment: Which line throw this exception? Does this issue happen to the specific project? Share us the build detials in command.

Comment: Please see Builds Logs section, I updated it apparently this is coming internally while building the code in docker.